# What is the best way to compress and encrypt a collection of video, audio, photo's and text for Android

Tags: android, video, compression, bundle

I want to bundle up a collection of files (audio, video, jpeg and text), in such a way that a user cannot unpack and view them, without using my app (initially an android app). The bundle will be created on a web server (using Perl) which the user will down load an use my app to view the content. I would rather not have the files sitting on the android in an unpacked and unencrypted state - but I presume if I am using the resident android video viewer (etc) that will be necessary.

Comment: Use AES Encryption. Compile the key into your app (not as one string, concat them using multiple variables to keep them secret from decompile attacks) for decryption and use the same key for encryption on your server. Bam.

Answer (score -1):

How paranoid do you want to be and do you need offline viewing?  If yes to offline viewing, anyone dedicated enough will be able to get your data.  If no, you can do it via encryption but the encryption key will need to be downloaded as needed from a central server with authentication of the client done server side.  You'll need to use files that are small enough to decrypt in RAM of course (or else you'll have unencrypted copies lieing around).  And you'll need to not use external viewers (they'll need to be passed a file URI to read the file), and not use any API for internal viewers that won't accept a stream of bytes for data.

Or you can realize that this whole level of paranoia isn't worth it, your data really isn't that valuable, and that its not worth the 10s of thousands of dollars of time to deal with all this.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not MY data to be paranoid with. I think I have a duty of care to protect it as much as is reasonably possible.

Comment: Depends on what your app does, which we have no idea.  Maybe you're transferring medical records, in which case you should be.  But generally businesses tend to think their data is something special and it really isn't, or to be terrified of OMG PIRACY!!!!  In 99% of cases, if you allow someone to view it you shouldn't care if they can copy it elsewhere.